# How to refresh datagridview after saving a record from another pc

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I would like to ask any suggestion on updating the datagridview from **PC 1** after saving a record from **PC 2**. I think there's a work around for this using a timer control but I think if I will execute a command every(let's say) 5 to 10 seconds. I'm executing a command that's not again I think necessary.

So again what are the other way on updating the DataGridView from **PC 1** after saving a record from **PC 2**. Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually asking? Do you want to know how to know when there's new data to display or how to display that new data, because they are two different things.  If it's displaying the new data then it's just fdata, so you retrieve and display it like any other data.  If you want to ensure that you only retrieve new data then you need a way to identify new data. The obvious way to do that is to set the current date and time when you save it and then you can retrieve only data that has a date and time later than the last time you queried.

Comment: MySQL has a couple of primitive functions for watching for this sort of thing.  If you need it to do more than just watch inserts, it can get a tad more complicated.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I apologize. I do not know where or how to ask since I think this kind of situation requires few experience on **vb.net** and **mysql**.  I will try to explain it on a scenario:  I deployed a **vb.net program** on two machines both using datagridview. When a user(**PC1**) inserts or update a record on the database. The datagridview on **PC2** should manually refresh or reload its record to retrieve what **PC1** inserted or updated. I would like to know if there are any way that datagridview on **PC2** would refresh automatically when it detects a movement on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: All clients have to watch a timestamp on the server, that signals a change of the data. If the own timestamp is older than the server timestamp, then the client has to refresh. The server timestamp will be updatet every time a change is made.

Other way: all active clients have to register at the server and if a change is made, the server sends a signal to the clients.

Comment: Thanks! May i ask how will the client watch the timestamp on the server? using what and how? Thanks again.

Comment: @Erol.404 watching a timestamp on the server would lead to a polling method, which is not that cool, because it causes many unnecessary traffic and requests if no change was made. I would suggest the other way, since it only causes a communication when  a change was made and has the advantage to easily implement some communication features on top, with less effort.